# How to switch between low latency and generic kernels?

Tags: boot, kernel

I have installed a low latency kernel to help Ardour's performance while recording audio. On boot-up, it appears I can select which 'version' of Ubuntu I want; the two choices are 'Ubuntu' and 'Ubuntu low-latency'. However, when I run `uname -r` with either one, I get `3.14.0-031400-lowlatency`.

Why the separate boot up options if 'Ubuntu' is the same as 'Ubuntu low-latency'? Is there a way to actually boot-up with the generic kernel? Is there a reason to, or are there drawbacks from using the low latency kernel while doing my day-to-day tasks?

Comment: You have to reboot to switch. With modern CPU, however, it is rare you need a low latency kernel. At any rate, it sounds as if your grub is not configured to boot the correct kernel. There is a nice discussion here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/126664/why-to-choose-low-latency-kernel-over-generic-or-realtime-ones

Comment: I am rebooting, but it appears no matter which one I select, it loads the low latency one regardless

Comment: If you do not need it, remove it. If you wish to keep it, configure grub, manually, to boot the correct kernel. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Comment: For anyone who upgraded to Artiful 17.10 and landing here first from a search, see [bug 1728760](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aufs-tools/+bug/1728760).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a nice fix with dual listing:

- Low-latency

  1. Download `ubuntustudio-default-settings` package from http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntustudio-default-settings (choose your release through links in the top right corner)
  2. Extract it.
  3. Copy `09_lowlatency` file to `/etc/grub.d/`

     If you don't want low-latency entry to be the top one, rename it to `11_lowlatency` so it will be processed after `10_linux`.
- Generic and other kernel types

  Edit `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` as explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/471180/26246) to exclude low-latency kernel from its listing.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Sneetsher is valid, but, just as an alternative, I used a different solution. If you want to have separate entries in GRUB in `/etc/grub.d/` for `generic` and `lowlatency` kernels, you can just make a copy of the file `09_lowlatency`. If you want the new entry to be the first one, name it something like `08_generic`, but you can choose the ordering as you prefer (e.g. you can have `08_lowlatency` and `09_generic`). Then, edit the copied file and replace all the occurrences of `lowlatency` with `generic`, and update GRUB. That should give you the two options on boot.