# What are the dangers of upgrading kernel from 4.18.0-13 generic to 5?

Tags: kernel

I'm in the mood to break things.

Current system:

```
Linux Kublai-1888 4.18.0-13-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 09:04:24 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I didn't even know 5 existed! Are there any benefits I should be aware about? I'm going to uninstall my graphics drivers beforehand since it'll probably break. Wish me luck! If you've got a way to reinstall pip2/pip3 with proper  metadata + $PATH + so it's not broken I'd like that too.

Reference materials I will use:

[Reinstalling CUDA, which I use to enhance my gfx performance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530043/removing-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-and-installing-new-one#530050https://askubuntu.com/questions/530043/removing-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-and-installing-new-one#530050)

[Info on different types of kernels](https://askubuntu.com/questions/687784/how-to-switch-between-low-latency-and-generic-kernels)

[Kernel sources](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/)

[Official docs on Nvidia headers and making sure you don't screw yourself](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html)

[More of the above, but Github guy, so you can trust it more](https://gist.github.com/wangruohui/df039f0dc434d6486f5d4d098aa52d07)

Comment: `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge cuda` worked. `apt list --installed | grep cuda` got the last bit. Now going for `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit gcc-6` and will return with some dope.

Comment: Even though I answered your question I voted along to close it as "too broad" as it stands now. If you rephrased your question to something like: "What can I do if I install Kernel 5 and it doesn't work" I will retract my vote. +1 though as it is a good question others will be interested in.

Answer (score 2):

After installing a mainline Linux kernel such as version 5 you can still reboot and select the previous version.

At the Grub menu select **Advanced Options**. A sub menu appears showing all your previously installed kernels that have not been auto removed or manually removed.

Comment: Interesting. `sudo apt autoremove` had removed those, if I recall. Doesn't really matter in the end unless I have issues with 5, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Everything went fine. It's always good to uninstall everything before upgrading.

Comment: Can you post the differences or any review?

Comment: Can't really say much...faster, marginally. No bugs. I would do it mainly for security benefits.